# How do you get an iPhone's Device Name in C#

Tags: c#, iphone, winforms

I'm writing a C# winforms application that will transfer files from an iPhone or iTouch using the [Manzana](http://code.google.com/p/manzana/) library.

My iPhone is called Mark's iPhone and I want this to display in the application. I can't find any simple way of finding this. Can anyone help. Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon the vague answer, but I don't have the manzana sources in front of me.

To get the device's name, you need to call the AMDeviceCopyValue() function with the reference you have to the device and the key "DeviceName".

Pseudocode:

```
AMDeviceCopyValue(device, 0, "DeviceName");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't work with my version of the Manzana source but I should be able to hack it from here.

Answer (score 1):

First, go download the [iTunes COM SDK](http://developer.apple.com/sdk/). Create a new project and reference the library. I don't know anything about the library you're talking about, but I imagine it's built off of the SDK, so you may already have a reference.

The C# source code snippet below should get you the name of your iPhone. If it doesn't work, try `ITSourceKindDevice` instead of iPod.

```
iTunesApp app = new iTunesAppClass();
IITSourceCollection sources = app.Sources;
foreach(IITSource s in sources)
{
if(s.Kind == ITSourceKind.ITSourceKindIPod)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Type: " + s.Name);
}
```